# When i rezise my browser window my images rezise to fit it, but if i zoom in or out the images stay the same size

Tags: html, css

How can i solve this? The images are set to percentages and nothing happens if i set a height percentage.

Relevant html:

```
<div class="header">
   <img src="pictures/header.png" width="30%">
   </div>
```

Css for that div:

```
.header {
margin: auto;
width: 70%;
padding: 1%;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,"serif";
font-size: 130%;
color: #e5e5e5;
background-color: #232323;
```

Html for the second image:

```
<div class="main">
<h1> bla bla bla </h1>
<img class="right" src="bilder/wave.gif">
<p> bla bla bla </p>
</div>
```

Css for both classes mentioned:

```
.right{
    float: right;
    width: 15%;     
}

.main{ 
margin:auto;
width: 70%;
padding:1%;
align: center;
text-align:left; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,"serif";
color: #2b2b2b;
font-size: 130%;
background-color:rgba(178, 92, 42, 0.5);
background-image: url("../pictures/scroll.jpg");
background-size: 100%;
padding-bottom:2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you zoomin that doesn't effect the windows height/width and the percentage unit works based on the height/width therefore nothing happens.

the zoom supported by the browsers is merely for text, because the font-sizes uses pixel units.

try setting a fixed width using `px` then zoomin and see it grows and shrink.

Answer (score 0):

The best method for solving this browser zooming problem is "**box-sizing:border-box**",

```
* { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```